# BufferedReader always resets to last character in a file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am having trouble reseting BufferedReader to a random point in reading a txt file. My example input text in a file is: `number = 10;`.
 Last part of code `System.out.println((char)c);` will print out `;` instead of `1`. 
What am I doing wrong in this simple example?
My code:

```
String filePath = "data.txt";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
String line = "";
int c = 0;
while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {     
    if((char)c == '1') {
        br.mark(1000);
    }
    System.out.print((char)c);
}
br.reset();
c = br.read();
System.out.println((char)c);
```

Comment: Are you reading more than 1000 characters after you call mark?

Comment: @ControlAltDel no

Answer (score 0):

From using your code and some dummy `.txt` file I made using the `number=10;` as a line. `c = br.read()` returns `0`.

The java.io.BufferedReader.mark(int) method marks the current position in the stream. Invoking reset() will reposition the stream to this point, from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedreader_mark.htm).

So essentially it prints the character after the character you have assigned as the mark.

If you wish to print the rest of the line you could use:

`String line = br.readLine();`

If you do want to get the `1` for some reason, you could simply modify your code as such:

`c = br.read()+1;`

Answer (score -2):

I tried your code, first of all it is printing '0' in my case.

Actually when you use `reset` its putting cursor after `1` not before `1`.

But according to your need you need output as `1`, which can be possible if you use `mark` on the character before `1`.

Like I wanted to print `r` so I put mark on `e` as shown below:

```
while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {     
    if((char)c == 'e') {
        br.mark(1000);
    }
    System.out.print((char)c);
}
br.reset();
c = br.read();
System.out.println((char)c);
```

Hope it makes thing clear.